# Add Tag After and Before elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, tags, html

Assuming I have this markup:

```
<li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Item 1</a> 5 </li>
<li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Item 2</a> 9 </li>
<li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Item 3</a> 4 </li>
<li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Item 4</a> 3 </li>
<li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Item 5</a> 7 </li>
```

I want insert a span tag after `<li><a>item</a>` and before `</li>` thus being.

```
<li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Item 1</a><span> 5 </span></li>
<li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Item 2</a><span> 9 </span></li>
<li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Item 3</a><span> 4 </span></li>
<li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Item 4</a><span> 3 </span></li>
<li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Item 5</a><span> 7 </span></li>
```

I want to do with jQuery. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
$('li.cat-item a').each(function(){
    $(this.nextSibling).wrap('<span>');
});
```

This [wraps](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) the text node after the `<a>` (i.e. its [nextSibling](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-6AC54C2F)) in a `<span>`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a7jtJ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This will insert an empty `span` tag after each `a` tag in `li.cat-item`:

```
$('li.cat-item a').after('<span />');
```

See [jQuery - after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)